# WebCryptoAPI - Does it support signing with cryptographic tokens?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, digital-signature, webcrypto-api

I would like to be able to sign data on the browser using 100% JavaScript and cryptographic token based keys.

From what I have seen so far, all old implementations of this functionality are being discontinued (e.g. even `new ActiveXObject("CAPICOM.Store");` doesn't seem to work in IE11 any more since it throws an error! - I don't know if I am missing something... Perhaps because I run it in the Console window...).

I have looked into the specs of the WebCryptoAPI (that is supposed to be the be the new supported way):

http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#SubtleCrypto-method-sign

...and then at this (which is more clear, organized and helpful):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn302332(v=vs.85).aspx

...and I saw that it allows you to create new keys (`generateKey`), but I am not sure if it supports using keys from tokens. There is an `importKey` but from the description it seems that is not what I need in order to sign with an existing key that the OS can see.

Does this web-standard aim at allowing that kind of functionality? Can I use it as it is now and achieve my goal?

Can I do anything better at least in Firefox that has a device manager (Options->Certifivates->Security Devices)?

Related questions:

[Accessing signing/encryption in a browser's Keystore using JavaScript - sample code? (WebCryptoAPI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567858/accessing-signing-encryption-in-a-browsers-keystore-using-javascript-sample-c)

[js signature on chrome with OS keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684734/js-signature-on-chrome-with-os-keystore?lq=1)

**UPDATE:**

I have also found this PDF:
http://webpki.org/papers/PKI/x509-webcrypto-extension-scheme.pdf

From what I have seen, there is no `window.crypto.subtle.KeyStore` in any of the browsers, so I guess this is wild dreams that people have for the distant future...

**UPDATE2:**
This was the reason I couldn't load the ActiveX in IE11: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5157766/2173353

So, at least, there is one old way still working...

Comment: At the moment WebCrypto has no mechanisms to access certificate and/or key stores at all. Everybody hopes that this changes and it's not clear what standard developers thought when omitted this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently not. Hardware or software tokens of the user are *still* unavailable. See the comment for Eugene (on the question) for slightly more information.