# Using PKI certificate to sign with the browser

Tags: javascript, pki, pkcs#11, webcrypto-api, webcrypto

I have a pretty simple use case. The user of my web application should be able to sign outputs on certain workflow steps.
The website is secured via mutual ssl, so when a user signs in he is prompted to pass his certificate. This works fine, so I *know*, that the browser can access the certificates (from the PKI Card via Firefox's crypto-module or the Windows' keystore in Chrome).
From that point it should be easy to use a user's certificates from within the browser. But it seems that there is no an obvious way.

What I tried:

#### google

There are some StackOverflow questions (but all seem to be old):

- [Accessing signing/encryption in a browser's Keystore using JavaScript - sample code? (WebCryptoAPI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567858/accessing-signing-encryption-in-a-browsers-keystore-using-)
- [js signature on chrome with OS keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684734/js-signature-on-chrome-with-os-keystore)

#### webcrypto api

This API seems to be great. Also that [use case](https://www.w3.org/community/webcryptoapi/2012/03/28/a-draft-of-korea-webcrypto-usecase/) seems to be exact what I need. But the [final implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API) seems not have [that capabilities](https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/web-crypto/import-key/index.html)

#### pkijs

As webcrpypto api exactly that capability seems not to be [implemented](https://pkijs.org/#examples)

#### webcrypto key discovery

Is that the [missing link](https://www.w3.org/TR/webcrypto-key-discovery/)? I'm not sure....

Why a new question? As we have 2020 now, the older questions and answers contain a lot of outdated stuff (active-x, java-applets), so I hope that we can get a clear and obvious answer making it possible without any workarounds.

**Update**: I'm afraid it's still impossible: https://techblog.bozho.net/electronic-signatures-using-the-browser/

Comment: You cannot get the certificate from the host system using JavaScript. You would need something with filesystem access. It would be possible to run a program on the host pc that sends the certificate as PEM to a chrome extension that can interact with your website, but that would require the user to install the program that gets the cert and the extension that uses it.

Comment: Apparently you can [access smartcards using a chrome extension only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55755768/1487756)

Comment: Please look at https://fortifyapp.com/. It allows to get and use certificates from system storage and PKCS#11 tokens. Here is an example of how to create CMS package using Fortify application https://codesandbox.io/s/fortify-demo-2b9x8

Comment: I need to do the same. Did you finally succeed ?

Comment: No, i gave it up without a solution.