# Digitally sign data in browser using smart card or certificate

Tags: browser, digital-signature

I need to create digital signature of some XML data with a client certificate(smart card) using web browser. Usually I used to do it with a java applet executing on the client side. The benefit being multiplatform in terms of OS and browsers.

However this option is getting increasingly harder and harder to implement and support in the long term. Virtually all browsers require some sort of action in order to execute such applet, code signing with a trusted certificate is almost mandatory nowadays, new manifest attributes and so on. Well there is nothing wrong with some extra layer of security and I am ok with that.

However Google Chrome as of April 2015 has stopped support for Java applets (and other plugins as well) - there is a configuration switch but it won't be available for much longer as stated [here](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml).
Mozilla Firefox does not have end of support date for NPAPI but they call it "[legacy technology](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Plugins)".
As for IE - it does not support plugins in Modern UI.

So with Java applets no longer really a universal option what are my choices?
What I have investigated so far:

- ActiveX - IE only
- Silverlight - no access to certificates at all and as a plugin faces the same limitations as Java
- Browser specific extensions; For example Firefox up until version 33 used to have window.crypto.signText but not anymore
- local applications installed on the client - not easy to install, support, develop and update for several OS and their different versions.
- Web Cryptography - "only basic cryptographic functions", no certificates support

I ran out of ideas. All suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Just one correction: crypto.signText() has been removed from Firefox but is currently available as [signTextJS](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/signtextjs/) extension.

Comment: Yup, your approach will continue to get harder and harder to achieve. That's on purpose. The goal of the browsers is to become more and more secure and signing data on a smart card doesn't fit that model. 

Instead, leave the smartcards behind. Store private keys centrally (or in the cloud) and sign centrally. Your signers will still have exclusive control over their private keys, they just won't carry them in a smart card.

The browsers will support better and better authentication of the user (eg see [FIDO](https://fidoalliance.org/about/overview/)), but not signing on smart cards.

Comment: I understand your point but private keys and certificates are distributed on smart cards at least for my particular case. There is a legal reason for this (in my country) - so called qualified digital electronic signatures should reside on a hardware device ("..is created by a device for secure signature creation..").  On the other hand - central certificate authority is possible but if and only if my application issues the certificates to my clients - which is not always the case.

Comment: [CoSign](http://www.arx.com/about/press-room/releases/cosign-common-criteria/) has received Common Criteria certification as a centralized SSCD that can be used with qualified signatures. It works well with web apps. The signers' keys reside in a hardware protected box on the network. The signers' keys can be signed by your local qualified certificate authority via a CSR.

Answer (score 3):

I did same research few weeks ago, and the first option for me is migrate to firefox (at least for now).

An alternative, could be migrate applets to JNLP java client application (maybe with some websocket/restful synchronization between java client/server/web page).

I think the options that you mentioned have less support among browsers than java applet.

Answer (score 2):

### Proprietary API available

I want to revive an answer previously deleted for lack of information. My answer does not provide complete info but since I had the same problem and stumbled upon this question, I'd like to share my findings.

I also have an additional requirement so that the browser signature works on "older" (IE9) browsers.

There is a web API at https://www.4identity.eu/ distributed by Italian smart card manufacturer Bit4id.

The 4identity API, however, is not really a full "web API" that relies on plain Javascript, as it still requires to download a Windows-only client (sic!). The client, as far as I could understand, responds on a custom `keychain` URL protocol (I had a past Oauth-2 related question on how to handle desktop applications....) which is not standard according to my findings. The client has access to the key store so it can upload the signed file to the remote web service who is being polled by the Ajax page.

I need to do some paperwork to get full API access, and I have no information about pricing. Still, I deem worth to give a detailed look.

### Part 2 of the question

Supporting a real digital signature from browser requires **browser vendors** and W3C, who oversees web standards, to do a lot of effort, maybe just the same effort they did for standardizing DRM solutions in HTML5 for sake of multimedia companies (criticism mode on). Currently **there is** WebCrypto standard but according to [research](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API) it is not available in "mainstream browsers"

Digital signing a remote file with a smart card requires access to the key store and the implementation of cryptography libraries. An open source implementation of PaDES/CaDES is expectable by the community, but without a final implementation of a standard way to access the key store the smart card cannot be accessed.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26732739/471213).

This additional part of the answer does not apply to my case as I require this to work on older browsers.

Disclaimer: I am **not** affiliated with Bit4id but I know them since I had the opportunity to integrate their work in my apps. One of our customers is a Bit4id partner

Comment: WebCrypto support is pretty decent, even was as of Feb 16th, see - http://caniuse.com/#search=crypto if you need to work downlevel you can use https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/webcrypto-liner. That does not solve the smart card issue but thought it relevant for others to capture here.